# Postgres autocomplete not working in version 10

Tags: postgresql, postgres-10

Whenever i press up/down arrows, the command history is not getting displayed and whenever i press tab, autocomplete is not happening.

Comment: Autocomplete feature is not postgres feature, and postgres version is irrelevant. It is a feature of the client you use to connect to postgres. So which one is it? Psql? Pgadmin? What version? Most likely you just need to upgrade the client.

Comment: am using psql - 14.5

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/app-psql.html

Comment: Which operating system are you using? Tab-completion in `psql` is not supported on Windows